# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "ReferralNumMedia" in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I need to convert a certain JSON string to a Java object. I am using Jackson for JSON handling. I have no control over the input JSON (I read from a web service). I added all the fields in the POJO class which come from the request but still, I'm getting the same error - Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ReferralNumMedia". I'm using Twilio webhook and I need to store request that comes from Twilio.

Here is my sample code

```java
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TwWebHook {

    @JsonProperty("AccountSid")
    private String accountSid;

    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private String address;

    @JsonProperty("ApiVersion")
    private String apiVersion;

    @JsonProperty("Body")
    private String body;

    @JsonProperty("From")
    private String from;

    @JsonProperty("Label")
    private String label;

    @JsonProperty("Latitude")
    private String latitude;

    @JsonProperty("Longitude")
    private String longitude;

    @JsonProperty("MessageSid")
    private String messageSid;

    @JsonProperty("NumMedia")
    private String numMedia;

    @JsonProperty("NumSegments")
    private String numSegments;

    @JsonProperty("SmsMessageSid")
    private String smsMessageSid;

    @JsonProperty("SmsSid")
    private String smsSid;

    @JsonProperty("SmsStatus")
    private String smsStatus;

    @JsonProperty("To")
    private String to;

    @JsonProperty("MediaUrl0")
    private String mediaURL0;
    
    @JsonProperty("MediaContentType0")
    private String mediaContentType0;
    
    @JsonProperty("ErrorCode")
    private String errorCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("StructuredMessage")
    private String structuredMessage;
    
    @JsonProperty("ProfileName")
    private String profileName;
    
    @JsonProperty("WaId")
    private String waId;
    
    @JsonProperty("MessagingServiceSid")
    private String messagingServiceSid;
    
    @JsonProperty("ButtonText")
    private String buttonText;
    
    @JsonProperty("ButtonPayload")
    private String buttonPayload;
    
    @JsonProperty("ErrorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;
    
    @JsonProperty("Forwarded")
    private String forwarded;
    
    @JsonProperty("ReferralNumMedia")
    private String referralNumMedia;

   // Getters & Setters
}
```

I keep getting this error. I am not sure what is missing. Can someone help, please?

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "ReferralNumMedia" (class xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.wrapper.tw.TwWebHook), not marked as ignorable (26 known properties: "SmsMessageSid", "AccountSid", "Body", "Forwarded", "MediaUrl0", "NumSegments", "MessageSid", "From", "SmsStatus", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Address", "SmsSid", "StructuredMessage", "To", "ButtonPayload", "MessagingServiceSid", "ApiVersion", "ButtonText", "MediaContentType0", "WaId", "Label", "NumMedia", "ErrorCode", "ProfileName", "ErrorMessage"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.wrapper.tw.TwWebHook["ReferralNumMedia"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:987)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1974)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1701)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1679)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:330)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4309)
        ... 37 more
```

Comment: If you check the list of available properties, you'll see that `ReferralNumMedia` isn't one of them. There is `NumMedia`...

Comment: Hi, @M.Deinum Thank you for responding, but in the request, we've `ReferralNumMedia` and `NumMedia`. `NumMedia` is already there now I added one more field `ReferralNumMedia` and it is causing problems.

Comment: Again look at the error message, the **response** doesn't have that field...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jackson doesn't see your property in POJO.
It prints: 26 known properties and I counted 27. Haven't you forgotten getter/setter for this one field? Maybe you haven't recompiled class?